# MSExcel: Is it possible to make an adaptive formula through reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Example:

[image: screenshot of example]

Desired result:

[image: wanted results]

(Please note that the red values in the first image above are made red to signify that they are actually functions, imagine adding an "=" sign before them.)

I have number values from the J column and the K column. In the L column next to them, I have referenced a nearby cell N2. N2 contains my formula J2+K2 which obviously adds the values of cells J2 and K2. However, it will not work on J3 and K3 because the formula is still J2+K2. **Is there a way for the formula to adapt to it?** If not, any suggestion about making this work easier would help! Thank you.

Comment: What are some formula examples? Are they simply add/divide/multiply/subtract the values in that row only, or could they more elaborate calculations that may or may not involve other rows?

Comment: It would be easy in Office 365 with dynamic arrays. Or you could write a VBA macro.

Comment: @Isolated Well, if this project that I am working on is the basis, then I would only be involving the same row at a time.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I do plan on learning them. I will look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the formula `=J2+K2` in cell `L2`. Then copy that cell, select cells `L3:L7`, and paste.

Alternatively, you can use the [fill handle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) to drag the formula in `L2` down to the cells below. The references will adjust automatically.

You don't need anything in `N2`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, I really wanted a way (if there's any) to make that referencing so when I change the formula on N2, it would automatically change all the referenced formulas on column L without having to manually drag it below. Especially if I am making a really long-columned worksheet. Can you help me?